# SubSurf modifier does not fill corner

Tags: modifiers

The boundary edges of this tape consist of sharp edges (crease = 1), the interior edges are soft (crease = 0). Nevertheless, the SubSurf modifier does not fill up all the way to the corner. How come?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why myself. The long edge that starts from the corner (yellow line) isn't a sharp edge. When I changed its crease to 1, the corner filled up nicely ...